# GWT DataGrid Good Tutorials?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

Could anyone point me to good GWT DataGrid tutorial?

The existing sample code are presented as fete de complete and I'd like something that walkthru in steps of using a DataGrid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though it's not a tutorial I've found that the best way to learn how the DataGrid works is to go through [this example](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) and build one yourself in parallel. It might take a while to understand it all but it's worth doing. All the important steps are there.